# Why do I get this Debug Assertion Failed? Expression: list iterator not dereferenceable

Tags: c++, assertions, debugging

I'm trying this example in the (translated to dutch) book of Bjarne Stroustrup (C++):

```
#include <vector>
#include <list>
#include "complex.h"

complex ac[200];
std::vector<complex> vc;
std::list<complex> l;

template<class In, class Out> void Copy(In from, In too_far, Out to) {
    while(from != too_far) { 
            *to = *from;
            ++to;
            ++from;
            }
}

void g(std::vector<complex>& vc , std::list<complex>& lc) {
    Copy(&ac[0], &ac[200], lc.begin());           // generates debug error
    Copy(lc.begin(), lc.end(), vc.begin());       // also generates debug error
}

void f() {
    ac[0] = complex(10,20);
    g(vc, l);
}

int main () {
    f();
}
```

** Compiling and Linking goes successful (0 errors/warnings)**

But at runtime I get this error:

**Debug Assertion Failed!**

Program: path to exe

file: \program files\ms vs studio 10.0\vc\include\list

Line: 207

Expression: list iterator not dereferenceable

For information on how your program can cause an assertion failure, see the Visual C++ documentation on asserts.
(Press retry to debug the application)

Comment: This is off-topic for this site and belongs on SO. Please don't re-ask this question there as this can be migrated. A good rule to follow is if your question has you in front of your IDE it belongs on SO. If it has you in front of a whiteboard it belongs on Programmers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the following erroneous:

```
Copy(&ac[0], &ac[200], lc.begin());           // generates debug error
Copy(lc.begin(), lc.end(), vc.begin());       // also generates debug error
```

Your `Copy()` function overwrites elements starting at the iterator supplied as the third argument. Therefore, the destination range has to be valid and large enough to accommodate all the elements being copied. Neither `lc` nor `vc` satisfy this, so the behaviour of your code is undefined.

One way to fix your code is by using [`std::back_inserter`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/back_inserter/).

Comment: You were right.. I found the error in my code and it seems indeed the destination range was not large enough. (I thaught it expanded automatically..) In fact it were empty lists and empty vectors. I had to fill the list<complex> l and the vector<complex> vc first with 200 empty complex objects. After that the copy function did it's work just fine..